# Designing a RDBMS schema. Represeting a subset

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have a (simplified) database schema that represents `card`, `card_sets` and `card_prints`.
A single `card` can be featured in multiple `card_sets`. A valid `(card, card_set)` pair is referred to as a `card_print`.

I also need to model a relationships `card_have` and `card_want`.

The `card_have` must be able to express expresses "I have this card from a particular set."

The `card_want` must be able to express both of the following:

1. "I want this card; I do not care about the set it is from."
2. "I want this card; I only want it to be from sets ". (Alternatively, consider this easier variant this: "I want this card; I only want it to be from this set".)

The `card_want` boils down to representing a subset of the possible `card_prints` of the `card`.

This is what I have so far (a bit simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "card"
  ( id    BIGSERIAL  NOT NULL  UNIQUE  PRIMARY KEY
  , name  TEXT       NOT NULL  UNIQUE
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "card_set"
  ( id    BIGSERIAL  NOT NULL  UNIQUE  PRIMARY KEY
  , name  TEXT       NOT NULL  UNIQUE
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "card_print"
  ( id           BIGSERIAL  NOT NULL  UNIQUE  PRIMARY KEY
  , card_id      BIGINT     NOT NULL  REFERENCES "card"(id)
  , card_set_id  BIGINT     NOT NULL  REFERENCES "card_set"(id)
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "card_have"
  ( id             BIGSERIAL  NOT NULL  UNIQUE  PRIMARY KEY
  , card_print_id  BIGINT     NOT NULL  REFERENCES "card_print"(id)
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "card_want"
  ( id       BIGSERIAL  NOT NULL  UNIQUE  PRIMARY KEY
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "card_want_set"
  ( card_want_id    BIGINT     NOT NULL  REFERENCES "card_want"(id)
  -- One the following two lines:
  -- , card_print_id  BIGINT  NOT NULL  REFERENCES "card_print"(id) 
  -- , card_set_id  BIGINT  NOT NULL  REFERENCES "card_print"(id) 
  );
```

The "I do not care about the set the card is from" would be represented by not associating any `card_print_id`/`card_set_id` with the `card_want` instance.

The problem of these solutions is that the associated `card_print_id`/`card_set_id` might not correspond to the `card_id`. This could be alleviated a bit by introducing a constraints on the `card_print_id`/`card_set_id`, but that still seems a bit inelegant and suboptimal.

The solution to the easier variant might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "card_want"
  ( id       BIGSERIAL  NOT NULL  UNIQUE  PRIMARY KEY
  , card_id  BIGINT     NOT NULL  REFERENCES "card_print"(id)
  , card_set_id  BIGINT  REFERENCES "card_set"(id) -- NULL means "I do not care about the set."
  );
```

It shares the problem of the solution to the harder variant.

Is there a better and more elegant way to approach this problem (either the harder or the easier variant)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem source is that you have designed your connection tables with surrogate primary keys(id column). 
One of the disadvantages of using surrogate primary key is [disassociation:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) 
The values of generated surrogate keys have no relationship to the real-world meaning of the data held in a row. When inspecting a row holding a foreign key reference to another table using a surrogate key, the meaning of the surrogate key's row cannot be discerned from the key itself. Every foreign key must be joined to see the related data item. 
**This can also make auditing more difficult**, as incorrect data is not obvious.

So I think If you design your tables with non surrogate keys and using unique keys when necessary, the problem could be solved.
A draft design would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "card"
  ( id    BIGSERIAL  NOT NULL  UNIQUE  PRIMARY KEY
  , name  TEXT       NOT NULL  UNIQUE
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "card_set"
  ( id    BIGSERIAL  NOT NULL  UNIQUE  PRIMARY KEY
  , name  TEXT       NOT NULL  UNIQUE
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "card_print"  -- (card_id + card_set_id) are the PRIMARY key
  ( card_id      BIGINT     NOT NULL  REFERENCES "card"(id) PRIMARY KEY
  , card_set_id  BIGINT     NOT NULL  REFERENCES "card_set"(id) PRIMARY KEY
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "card_have" -- card_set_id + card_id is the  PRIMARY KEY
  ( card_id      BIGINT     NOT NULL  REFERENCES "card_print"(card_id) PRIMARY KEY
  , card_set_id  BIGINT     NOT NULL  REFERENCES "card_print"(card_set_id) PRIMARY KEY      
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "card_want" -- card_id  is the PRIMARY KEY 
  ( card_id  BIGSERIAL  NOT NULL  UNIQUE  PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES "card(id)"
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "card_want_set" (card_id  + card_set_id) is the PRIMARY KEY 
  ( card_id  BIGSERIAL  NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES "card_print(card_id)"
    ,card_set_id  BIGINT     NOT NULL PRIMARY REFERENCES "card_print"(card_set_id)
  );
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. I think this still has problem expressing "I do not care what set the card is from" (as opposed to "I want the card to be from any **current** set").

The reason I gave every card print an id is that there is an official id for every card print that I want to store in the database as well, so I have used it as the primary key for the `card_print` table.

Comment: Having the relation to card table in card-want doesn't satisfy the "I do not care what set the card is from" ?